# Como alterar o nome da aplicação compilada?

Tags: android, android-studio

Como alterar o nome "app-release" que fica após compilar a aplicação android ?

Comment: uma curiosidade: porque precisas modificar isto depois da aplicação ser compilada? não poderia por exemplo, duplicar o projeto e compilar já com o nome correto?

Comment: http://www.thiengo.com.br/mudar-icone-de-sua-app-android-quando-usuario-ja-a-instalou do mesmo jeito que muda o icone vc pode mudar o nome do app... acho que pode te ajudar...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Boa noite! Percebi que não responderam a pergunta e tive esse mesmo problema. Encontrei a solução e vim compartilhar.

Acesse o AndroidManifest.xml do seu projeto. Ele é um dos últimos itens do seu projeto. Depois de abrir, localize no Application a seguinte descrição: "android:label="@string/app_name".

Segurando o Ctrl e clicando em "@string/app_name", você será automaticamente direcionado para a página de Strings, onde você poderá alterar o nome do seu Aplicativo. O mesmo se aplica ao ícone ou ao tema do seu aplicativo.

Espero que a solução ajude outras pessoas.

Cordialmente.